# Comando venv no funciona para aislar mi entorno

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip, virtualenv

Cuando uso el comando `python3 -m venv env` y lo activo con `source env/bin/activate` no me sirve para aislar mi entorno virtual, ya que al usar los comandos `pip list` o `pip freeze` me sigue mostrando las librerías que tengo en mi entorno normal (tengo entendido que al activar el entorno virtual no debería haber mas de 2 librerías).

Comment: ¿a dónde apunta `which python`?

Comment: Bienvenido James-U a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.